# DateTime.ParseExact is not working, even though the format is correct

Tags: c#, .net

DateTime.ParseExact is giving an excpetion 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.' for the below code.

```
DateTime colValue = DateTime.ParseExact("11-Oct-18 11:15:13 AM", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Why this is not working?

Comment: Format is incorrect. Should be `MMM` instead of `MM`.

Comment: Also the " AM" in the input string. See [The "tt" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#ttSpecifier)

Comment: Also the format has four y's and the but input year only has two digits. Number of y's should match number of digits in year input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to fix in your mask:

- Long Month is => `MMM`
- You are using a short year => `yy`
- You need to indicate the AM/PM => `tt`
- Hour-Minute-Second should support one digit => `h:m:s`

```
DateTime colValue = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "11-Oct-18 11:15:13 AM", 
    "dd-MMM-yy h:m:s tt", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The above code works. But when the time is changed to "11-Oct-18 4:15:13 AM" it fails because "hour" has only one digit. How do I handle both the cases?

Comment: Edited @JerinSebastian

Answer (score 0):

This works because we replace hh with h, mm with m and ss with s, we also added tt to catch AM or PM:

```
        DateTime colValue = DateTime.ParseExact("11-Oct-18 11:15:13 AM", "dd-MMM-yy h:m:s tt",
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Thanks to @Jerin Sebastian

Comment: The above code works. But when the time is changed to "11-Oct-18 4:15:13 AM" it fails because "hour" has only one digit. How do I handle both the cases?

Comment: For a better answer, tell *why* this works. What did you change and why?